# How to delete files from Git index in the Intellijj IDEA project?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

How to delete files from Git index in the Intellijj IDEA project using Intellijj IDEA tools?

Comment: The better advice i can give you is to use the terminal for such kind of manipulation. It's not complicated and you have a much better control than such kind of IDE tools.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only manipulation you can do with IntelliJ in this manner is with the 'amend commit' feature.

When you next go to commit there is a checkbox (top right) called 'Amend commit'. If you select it, it will allow you to change the commit message and add files to the previous commit.

As for further manipulation of the index, such as undoing a number of commits. Take a look at the command line and the git reset command inparticular.

```
git help reset
```